# Facebook API: How to authenticate a web app

Tags: javascript, facebook, api, authentication, authorization

I am attempting to write a plugin for a webapp that integrates it with facebook using the Javascript API.  The application is installed by our customers on their own servers each with their own site names.  This poses a problem to me as Facebook wants me to specify a site url for the application.  This url is going to be different for every customer.  Creating a new application for each customer is not an option.

In my research of this problem it seems that I have to pretend to be a desktop app and follow that authentication path.  I cannot figure out how to do this.

Anyone have any idea how this can be done?

Comment: "Creating a new application for each customer is not an option." I think that's how Facebook expect it to work, though: you'd grant permissions for each of your customers' web apps to access your account separately, so you need separate application IDs. Although unless they restrict the oauth callback URL to the domain you specified when you set up the app, it might all just work as the one application anyway?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you going to host the app as a canvas app or outside facebook?

Is the url important to you? There is a strict one-to-one relation between base-url and application.

What many apps do is host the apps as directories in their domain.  For example http://crazy-fb-app.com/customername

That's your options basically if you want to use Javascript SDK.

If you're going to be using server side technology you could have  the user authorize the application while requesting permission to access user's data while he's offline.  in that case you will receive a non-expiring (or long-expiring) authentication token which you can use from the server to make Graph API calls on behalf of the user. For some stuff you can obtain an Application Auth token (which is shorter and non-user-specific) to make calls to the graph.

Rotem

Comment: I suspected this might be the only option.  Looks like the only way to do this is to write a connected service for our on premise apps.  Just makes things a tad more challenging ;)